# Using Docker : How to warp a web application to communicate with a nginx web server

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, dockerfile

I am new to using Docker. I want to rebuild my monolithic application using micro-services architecture approach.

**I have a Flask application server that needs to interact with nginx server. Traditionally we use Gunicorn that acts as uWSGI, but how can we do the same using Docker??**

Below is my code,

I have a Flask application, that asks the user to upload an excel file

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
default_key = '1'
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = "/app"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainpage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.form
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['submit'] == 'Check Results' :
     #TODO: copy the file into named volume
        f = request.files['file']
        filename = f.filename
        print os.getcwd()
        print os.listdir(os.getcwd())
        file1 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        f.save(file1)
        #TODO: ping the Classifier container
    return render_template('index.html')

#def receive_classifier_info():
    #TODO: the file has been received so succesfully display the message.
#pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is my templates/index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>key value lookup service</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
      <br>
      <h3>Select an input file</h3>
      <input type="file" name="file" value="Browse">
      <br>
      <h3>Insert a pic of the sample format</h3>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check Results">
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Next, Here is my Dockerfile to build this container.

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN pip install Flask==0.11.1 
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin
COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chown -R admin:admin /app
RUN chmod 755 /app
USER admin
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Next, I have my nginx server that acts as a reverse proxy.

I am stuck how to proceed from here. :(

**My Questions are :**

1) How should I wrap my application server to ensure that it communicates with the nginx container.
    -> I need to inform my application container whenever user clicks the submit button informing it to start processing.
    -> Next, once the processing is done it should inform the nginx server that ok processing is done.

2) Should I copy the index.html into /var/www/nginx/html ??

Thank you

Comment: Can anyone recommend one book that clearly describes the whole process in detail. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. You should start a Gunicorn process in your application container.  This will then run the process on `localhost:8000` (or your port of choice).
2. Then you'll create an nginx container that will proxy pass to your application.  In your server block youll have something like this:

   `proxy_pass http://web:8000;`

Its probably easier to run a `docker-compose` process.

Heres a snippet of the Dockerfile I have for my `web` service:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update OS
RUN sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Install Python
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-dev

COPY . /

# Install app requirements
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# Set the default directory for our environment
ENV HOME /
ENV PYTHONPATH=`$PWD`/..
WORKDIR /

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn"]
```

Heres a snippet from a docker-compose file I have for my flask app:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: ["app:app", "-w 4", "-t 90", "--log-level=debug", "-b 0.0.0.0:8000",  "--reload"]
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:1.13.1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - web
    links:
      - web:web
```

I really liked [this](https://www.capside.com/labs/deploying-full-django-stack-with-docker-compose/) tutorial for getting started with docker.  Even though its Django, its easily analogous to Flask.

Comment: Maybe I have missed some crucial news in the past two years, but I think you still need an application server for a flask app. Unless if you are talking about having a unix socket. Then that a different way of doing things.

Comment: Can you please recommend a book that explains these concepts in detail mainly building applications in Docker,  covering application server web server

Comment: Another question is how can I ping nginx server from application server manually to inform that processing of file is complete or how can I ping application server from nginx sever to tell OK user has uploaded the file, please start processing

Comment: I cant recommend a particular book but you might find some relevant sources here https://github.com/veggiemonk/awesome-docker

Comment: @ShivanandT Do you know if nginx supports such functionality?

Comment: No, this is my first introduction to servers, docker hence I am asking for a good book on this topic

Comment: I suggest you ask the nginx part in another question as your entire question is two-fold and it will break rules around here for being too broad.